# Why would sp.optimize.leastsq converge when sp.optimize.least_squares doesn't?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit my data and have so far used `sp.optimize.leastsq`. I changed to `sp.optimize.least_squares` to add bounds to the parameters, but both when I use bounds and when I don't the search doesn't converge, even in data sets `sp.optimize.leastsq` fitted just fine.

Shouldn't these functions work the same?

What could be the difference between them that makes the newer one not to find solutions the older one did?

Answer (score 0):

[leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9Cleastsq%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20wrapper%20around%20MINPACK%E2%80%99s%20lmdif%20and%20lmder%20algorithms.)
is a wrapper around MINPACK’s lmdif and lmder algorithms.

[least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) implements other methods in addition to the MINPACK algorithm.

> method{‘trf’, ‘dogbox’, ‘lm’}, optional
> Algorithm to perform minimization.
>
> - ‘trf’ : Trust Region Reflective algorithm, particularly suitable for large sparse problems with bounds. Generally robust method.
> - ‘dogbox’ : dogleg algorithm with rectangular trust regions, typical use case is small problems with bounds. Not recommended for problems with rank-deficient Jacobian.
> - ‘lm’ : Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as implemented in MINPACK. Doesn’t handle bounds and sparse Jacobians. Usually the most efficient method for small unconstrained problems.
>
> Default is ‘trf’. See Notes for more information.

It is possible for some problems that `lm` method does not converge while `trf` converges.

Comment: could you recommend an alternative fitting function with the ability to put bounds on the parameters that might work better, based on this?